# when writing arrays in c++ i tried including the array into another class but it wont work

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to coding in C++ and more used to some simple Java programming.

I made two classes, `class A(int)` and `class B`. I made an array filled with names, and I want `int A` to say one of the names from class `B`.

Example:

```
Class B {

   static string NPCnames[] { "John", "Mike", "Alex", "Adam"};
};

int A {

    cout << B::NPCnames[rand()]

};
```

It comes up with errors for the arrays (because I'm new I don't understand them)

Error message:

> Error  1   error C2864: 'Data::NPCnames' : a static data member with an in-class initializer must have non-volatile const integral type

Comment: Java tag removed -- what does this question have to do with Java?

Comment: no, this is a tobac++onist

Comment: This question has information on error C2864: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498433/resolving-only-static-const-integral-data-members-can-be-initialized-within-a-c

Comment: You should probably start by reading a [good book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: C++ (like Java) is case-sensitive. And `B::NPCnames[rand()]` - come on, at least do read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not generally useful.

Comment: Is `cout` allowed in an initializer?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - yeah.  The result of `<<` is `ostream&`.  It has a boolean conversion showing the status of the stream.  `A` should get assigned the standard integer conversion from that boolean.

Comment: @CrazyEddie that conversion is not allowed inside a braced initializer though

Answer (score 4):

You need...

```
class B { static string NPCnames[4]; };

string B::NPCnames[4] = { "blah",  "blah", ... };
```

Comment: thanks, but what if i were to replace the 4 in the `B::NPCnames[4]` with rand()?

Comment: Use a constructor and an additional variable representing the array size.

Comment: @Venture13 - then you'd have serious problems.

Comment: ok so then how about `B::NPCnames[rand() % 4]` also, i want the program to print out the `NPCnames` string. side-note: sorry for not understanding programming, like i said in the beginning of this post  `i'm new to coding` also, im new to this site.

Comment: @Venture13 The size of the array `NPCnames` cannot be variable. C++ forbids variable length arrays on the stack.

Comment: I guess here is a misunderstanding. @Venture13 You want to access a random element from the array. The `[4]` in the above code is the size of the array, which should not be random.

Comment: thanks @leemes also, i'll just send the code so everyone knows what's not working [Code](http://www.hastebin.com/izaxapulin.vala)