# how to define const string in the c++ method

Tags: c++

Inside class, I would like to define some const strings.however the compiler reports error when I use

```
class A {
static const std::string s = "test" 
};
```

inside the class. How to do that? Do I have to define the const outside the class defination?

Comment: As numerous answers have already stated, you must define the value outside the class declaration (typically not in the header file). You can, however, give a value to a built-in type (so sub 'int' for 'std::string' in your example and it will work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to define it outside.

```
class A {
  static const std::string s;
};

const std::string A::s("test");
```

Comment: @Christian , we can define integer const inside, is that right?

Comment: but for integer const you could also use enum.

Comment: integer constants can be defined inside a class!

Comment: static const int s = 10; is OK inside class, at least in VS2010. Wondering if this is c++ standard.

Comment: @user705414: It is indeed. Static const integral types, including boolean but not including pointer, can be initialized inside the class.

Comment: Currently the standard specifies that integral constants can be initialized inside class declaration. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370283/why-cant-i-have-a-non-integral-static-const-member-in-a-class) for a good explanation why it is so.

Comment: @user258808, @GMan: Note the need for careful use of vocabulary. They *can* be initialized inside the class, but such a declaration is *still not a definition*, and thus Boaz was correct to say they cannot be *defined* inside the class. Such static const integers live in a strange state where they can be used in contexts where a constant expression is required (e.g. array size), but if they're used in any other context then a definition is needed. See 3.2/2 and 9.4.2/2-4. C++0x changes the rules a bit, and introduces the term "odr-used".

Comment: @Steve: I'll give you that, but I doubt the nuance was intended. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be defined out side the class definition.

```
const std::string A::s = "test" ;
```

In `C++0x` initialization is allowed in the class definition itself ([result 1](http://ideone.com/ZIyZD)) . But I don't why for `std::string` type it isn't allowed ( [result 2](http://ideone.com/NHOeA) ).

Ahh .. from the error message it seems it is allowed only for **integral data** types.

Comment: You forgot the A::, as he wants it as a class member.

Comment: Christian Rau - Thanks, didn't notice it.

Comment: Any compiler supports C++0x standard?

Comment: @user - Of my knowledge, C++0x draft isn't released yet. But VS2010, already supports lambda functions.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize the static member outside the class (unlike C# where you can declare and initialize a member at the same place).

```
class A {
static const std::string s;
};

// initialize your static members outside of the class definition.
const std::string A::s = "Some text here";
```

Comment: Not only should they be outside of the class, they should also be (generally speaking) only defined in a .cpp file and not in a .h, or you'll likely violate the [One Definition] Rule(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

Comment: If I use #pragma once in the header, is that OK?