# Why would a non-constant static member have multiple definitions?

Tags: c++, static, constants, member, redefinition

C++ forces the programmer to define a non-constant static member outside the class, and the reason for this that I keep seeing is that if the static member was defined inside the class,
this would result in multiple definitions for the static member.  I understand that having
multiple definitions for a static member is bad, but I don't understand where these multiple
definitions would even come from. Shouldn't an initialized non-constant static member 
just go in the data section and that be the only definition?

```
struct Student {

   static int x = 4; // Why would this result in multiple definitions?

};
```

Also, I read in this other stackoverflow post that const static members are simply inlined into the code wherever it is used:
[Why can't I have a non-integral static const member in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370283/why-cant-i-have-a-non-integral-static-const-member-in-a-class) 
Is that handled by the preprocessor along with all the other directives? ( I will ask this in another post if needed, but I 
wasn't sure if it's worthy of a separate post ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would happen because/when your header gets included in multiple "translation units" (think .cpp files).

Each TU will then contain a copy of the definition.

At link time, they will clash. (The linker *links* the objects from each translation unit)

Comment: Could you please provide an example of this?

Comment: I'm assuming the OP was asking about why the construct is illegal

Comment: @sehe Yes, that's what I'm asking.

Comment: @sehe Actually, no example is necessary.  Your answer was sufficient in helping my understanding. Thank you.