# Why is in-class initialization of static const members in C++ restricted to integral data types?

Tags: c++

What are the reasons due to which the in-class initialization of static const members is restricted to integral data types in C++ ?

Comment: I always thought the rationale was the same as for why only integral types are allowed as template parameters, though I don't actually know what that rationale is.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: It's kind of still the case, though. Sure, you have an *alterative* mechanism with `constexpr`, but the restriction on `const` members is unchanged, isn't it?

Comment: For C++11  the rationale is different see [Constant expression initializer for static class member of type double](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30742288/1708801)

Comment: @KerrekSB Yup, correct you are. I was thinking of non-static members