# Wrong static const initialization that compiles and works

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

As far as I know, you can only initialize static const members in the same line of their declaration [if they are integral types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3531105/5302415) . However, I was still able to initialize and use some static const doubles:

```
// compiles and works, values are indeed doubles
struct Foo1{ 
    static const double A=2.5;
    static const double B=3.2;
    static const double C=1.7;
};

// compiles, but values are cast to int
struct Foo2{
    static const int A=2;
    static const int B=3;
    static const double C=B/A; //becomes 1
};

// does not compile, Foo3::B cannot appear in a constant-expression
struct Foo3{ 
    static const int A=2;
    static const double B=3;
    static const double C=A/B; 
};

// does not compile, a cast to a type other than an integral or enumeration
// cannot appear in a constant-expression
struct Foo4{ 
    static const int A=2;
    static const int B=3;
    static const double C=(double)A/B; 
};
```

Foo2 compiles but Foo2::C becomes 1, so maybe it is treated as an int as it is numerically one. Foo3 and Foo4 don't even compile, as expected. However, I don't understand why Foo1 both compiles and works correctly. Is this specific usage accepted? Is it because of some optimization? ( I've tried using -O1 and -O0)

Note: using GNU 5.2.0 with cmake and setting the standard to C++98. Switching to C++11 works fine ( that is, does not compile and asks to switch those members to constexpr).

Comment: Add the `-pedantic` switch, then gcc will even complain about `Foo1`. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/o35cpEXlgMedfvMT

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Foo1` case is indeed non-conforming and if we build using `-std=c++98 -pedantic` gcc will warn as follows (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/V1FWpGFmdyvODQ4U)*):

```
error: floating-point literal cannot appear in a constant-expression
 static const double A=2.5;
                       ^
warning: ISO C++ forbids initialization of member constant 'Foo1::A' of non-integral type 'const double' [-Wpedantic]
```

While compiling without `-pedantic` does not yield any error or warning (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/iYFAOf8fDVy3rP7d)*)

So this must be an extension and if we use clang using `-std=C++98 -pedantic` we see this message:

```
warning: in-class initializer for static data member of type 'const double' is a GNU extension [-Wgnu-static-float-init]
static const double A=2.5;
                    ^ ~~~
```

which seems to confirm this is an extension.

This restriction on floating point was kept in C++11 to remain compatible with C++03 and to encourage consistent use of constexpr see: [Constant expression initializer for static class member of type double](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30742473/1708801).

This is also the case for `Foo2` initializing `C` is allowed as an extension, the result of the division will be *int* since the type of the result depends on the type of the operands and does not depend on what you assign it to.

**Update**

This is a [depreciated extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Deprecated-Features.html#Deprecated-Features):

> G++ allows static data members of const floating-point type to be declared with an initializer in a class definition. The standard only allows initializers for static members of const integral types and const enumeration types so this extension has been deprecated and will be removed from a future version.

There is a more detailed [gcc bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11393) that discusses the validity of the extension and other related issues around it.

It seemed odd that using `-pedantic` was sufficient by itself to turn this into an error, there is a [gcc bug report that covers that](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55080).