# Using a const inside of a class - static vs not static

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

I have been trying to use a const as the size of an array inside a class declaration.  I know it works if I use a static const, but I am having trouble understanding why exactly.  More specifically, why can I use const for some data members in a class, but must specify static const for others, as follows:

```
class Test
{
public:
   static const int size = 10;   // 1. Works. Must be static to use it as size of array
   const int alpha = 20; // 2. Works, but cannot use as size of an array
   const double beta = 10.0; // 3. Works
   static const double gamma = 20.0; // 4. does not compile

   int table[size];  // Works with size, but not alpha
};
```

I have read many explanations, but have not found an one (or at least one I understand) specifically for what makes case 1 different from case 4, and why I need to make the const static for the array.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Edit: I'm using VS 2013 if that makes a difference

Comment: Size of arrays must be determined at time of compilation, therefore a static value must be used in the array declaration.

Comment: Outside of a class using [a const int would work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21273829/1708801) but in the class body it is not really const since you initialize it in the constructor so the value can change unlike `size`.

Comment: Case 4 uses a `double`.  Array sizes must be integers. A 2.5 element array would be a very interesting this to see, though. Like the average 2.5 child family.

Comment: Stupid comments aside, this is an interesting one. I don't know why `static const int` is valid but `static const double` isn't. Probably have to wait for a language lawyer to check in.

Comment: @Shafik that is the right answer, but he OP may need the explanation for why non static variables initialized that way are not actually const at compile time.

Comment: `const int alpha` could conceivably have different values in different `Test` objects if alpha is set in the constructor. Eg `Test():alpha(42){}` so it can't be used as a size.

Comment: By the way, if the value is known at compile time, that’s what `constexpr` is for.

Comment: @JohnDrouhard Shafik's answer does indeed help, along with the explanation from M.M below.  I think I now have a better understanding why the int needs to be static, but why can't the double also be static?

Comment: @JohnDrouhard I would have answered if I could have tracked down the standard quote that said that, I know it is the case but I don't see where the standard says so which is annoying.

Comment: We can find the double case covered in my answer to [Constant expression initializer for static class member of type double](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32813953/1708801). It may not be obvious to some since there used to a [gnu extension that allowed this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32813953/1708801).

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that:

```
const int alpha = 20;
```

is specifying that `20` is the *default value* which an object's `alpha` would get if you don't specify any other value.  However the class could easily have a constructor that overrides this, e.g.:

```
// header file:
struct S
{
    S();
    S(int);
    const int alpha = 20;
};

// .cpp file
S::S(int): alpha(30) { }
S::S(): alpha(40) {}
```

So the value of `alpha` could in fact be different for different objects. This means that the size of the object cannot depend on it, because all objects of the same type must have the same size and layout.

However in the case `static const int size = 10;`, this specifies right then and there that `size` does have value `10` and nothing later on can supersede this; so this can be used as array sizes and so on.  There is only a single `size` variable which is separate to any objects of the class.

Comment: This is a great way of explaining why the int must be static!  But why can't the double be static as well?

Answer (score 0):

> but have not found an one (or at least one I understand) specifically for what makes case 1 different from case 4,

An array size can only be an integral expression can be computed at compile time. Since `gamma` is of type `double`, you cannot use it as the size of an array.

> why I need to make the const static for the array.

A non-`static` member exists only as a member of an object of the class. Its  value is not usable without an object of the class. That throws up a catch-22 situation. You can't define the class without the size. You can't get the size without an object. A `static` member solves that problem.

Answer (score -1):

C++ doesn't allow non-constant values for the size of an array. That's just the way it was designed. Array's size must be determined at compile time.

If you want a dynamically sized array, you need to allocate memory for it (and free it with delete when you're done).

Comment: size is a constant expression thus allowed. Using a const int outside of the class body would work as well.

Comment: Please read the answer. What you said is the same thing I said... Re-read my answer before downvoting please...

Comment: He's right: this answer fails to explain the necessity of `static`.