# C++: "(static const double variable) cannot appear in constant-expression"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, static-variables, inlining

In `classA` I've got:

```
static const double alias_var = classB::const_var;
```

Then in `classB`:

```
static const double const_var = 1000.;
```

But the compiler keeps telling me:

> 'classB::const_var' cannot appear in a constant-expression.

Why not? The funny thing is if I change `classB::const_var` from a `double` to an `int`, the errors go away.

I inlined these variables for optimization. I hope that using floating-points doesn't prevent the optimization.

I'm using GCC 5.4.0 in a Ubuntu 64-bit environment. I'm sure the fact I'm using Qt4 has nothing to do with it.

Edit: my best workaround is to have in `classB`:

```
static const int const_var_int = 1000;
static const double const var = const_var_int;
```

and then in `classA` (any everywhere else) assign `const_var_int` to my floating-points. It gets rid of the errors. I don't know if it's defeating the purpose or what other consequences there are.

Comment: Short answer: use `constexpr` instead of `const`.

Comment: *"I inlined these variables for optimization."* - And did it become faster?

Comment: Floating point is treated differently than integral types mainly to stay compatible with C++03 see [Constant expression initializer for static class member of type double](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30742288/1708801) for more details.

Comment: Also note [deprecated gcc extension related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32814018/1708801)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: use `constexpr` instead of `const`.

Long answer: there are special provisions in old C++03 which allow class members which are static integral constants be used in constant expressions. This provision does not apply to non-integral (doubles).

With C++11, `constexpr` removed this limitation.

Comment: Looks like I've got a little to learn about these newer C++s. I'm not even sure which one I'm using and I'm getting "warning: identifier 'constexpr' is a keyword in C++11 [-Wc++0x-compat]"

Comment: @Opux I sincerely believe that Using C++2003 in 2018 is sin. Would you like to drive 2003 Toyota today?

Comment: I'm sure my 2007 Civic will still be going on strong in 3.5 years. That upgrade would require widespread changes and those decisions aren't up to me. I can mention it to my boss, but in the meantime, what should I do? I've edit my answer w/my best idea for a workaround

Comment: @Opux If such is the case, just don't use `double` as a constexpr

Comment: As long as your workaround works, it works. I am not sure if you are defeating the purpose since I do not know what is your purpose.

Comment: Abstraction and optimization. I think I can answer my own question about abstraction, but these errors make me think that the optimizer won't be able to be as clever w/doubles as it is w/ints. Oh and fwiw, "cerr << "and you are runnign: " << __cplusplus << endl;" reveals "and you are runnign: 199711"

Comment: @Opux Since this is non-standard extension of GCC anyways to allow this anyways (as standard doesn't allow for in-class initialization of const doubles). Looks like gcc 5.4 does indeed use in-class set value instead of reading the variable, so your optimization should be there. Beware - it is an error in later versions of GCC.

Comment: So you're saying I've harmed *portability*. Fortunately, I can fix that when the time comes