# Building error in constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I am using constexpr in my application and I am getting compilation error.

```
namespace {
   const int kLength = 1;
   const float kPiNumber = 3.14159265;
   constexpr float kCircumferenceArc()
   { return (2*kPiNumber*kLength) / 360; }
}
```

And the error I am getting is:

> read of non-constexpr variable 'kPiNumber' is not allowed in a constant expression
>      { return (2*kPiNumber) / 360; }

Could someone help me on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `const` integral variables with `constexpr` initializers are automatically made `constexpr`, but floating-point ones aren't. The solution is to make `kPiNumber` constexpr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constexpr variable must be initialized from values known at compile time. A const variable, like:

`const float kPiNumber = 3.14159265;`

for some historical reason 'const float' is not known at compile time.
To make it work, you must change this line to:

`constexpr float kPiNumber = 3.14159265;`

Here is the complete code:

```
namespace {
   const int kLength = 1;
   constexpr float kPiNumber = 3.14159265f;
   constexpr float kCircumferenceArc()
   { return (2*kPiNumber*kLength) / 360; }
}
```

Comment: "_for some historical reason 'const float' is not known at compile time._" One can make `const` variables, having the values of them, known only at runtime. `constexpr`explicitly states, that the value must be known at compile time.

Comment: I cover the [history of why floating point have exception wrt to constant expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30742473/1708801)