# The value of a const variable is or is not usable in a constant expression, depending on the variable type

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, constexpr

The following code is fine:

```
constexpr double square_cstxpr(double x) { return x * x; }

int main() {
    const int test = 5;
    constexpr double result = square_cstxpr((double)test);
}
```

However, if the type of `test` is changed from `const int` to `const double`, g++ gives the following error: `the value of 'test' is not usable in a constant expression`.

See the code and output of g++ here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fe9b176c2b23798

Could somebody explain that behavior?

Comment: Please add the code that doesn't compile instead of describing it.

Comment: @molbdnilo There is a link to coliru.

Comment: Builds fine for me!

Comment: In fact, it is the working case scenario that puzzles me. Calling a `constexpr` function with a non-`constexpr` argument should be illegal, but for some reason g++ is happy when the argument's type is `const int` :/.

Comment: @Geek which compiler (and which version) do you use?

Comment: @YSC It is legal, see for example A Tour of C++ (by Bjarne Stroustrup), section 1.7.

Comment: @YSC I thnk [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/370337/4342498) sheds light on it

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't get it, how is it related to `const int` variables being implicitly `constexpr`? Maybe my wording was bad. The answer of Edgar on the other hand confirms what I suspected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Non-`constexpr` but `const` variables must be of integer or enumeration type for them to be usable in constant expressions. See [[expr.const]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2.7):

> an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion unless it is applied to
>
> (2.7.1) a non-volatile glvalue of **integral or enumeration type**
>   that refers to a complete non-volatile const object with a preceding
>   initialization, initialized with a constant expression, or [..]

The reasons for this limitation must be mostly historical. Floating points have been handled with care when it comes to constant expressions; think non-type template parameters. This is due to their strongly platform dependent behaviour that renders compile time calculations less mathematical than they should be.

Comment: A couple years back, CWG rejected EWG's request to make `const float` usable in constant expressions, IIRC.

Comment: @T.C. y CWG did that to make everyone life so hard~?

Answer (score 12):

From [constant expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) (Core constant expressions):

> 10) Any other lvalue-to-rvalue implicit conversion, unless the
>   lvalue...
>
> a) **has integral or enumeration type** and refers to a complete non-volatile 
>   const object, which is initialized with a constant expression

It means, that here:

```
const int test1 = 5;
constexpr double result1 = square_cstxpr((double)test1);
```

`test1` is a constant expression, `square_cstxpr` can be called with `test1` as an argument at compile time and its result can be assigned to *constexpr variable* `result`.

On the other hand, here:

```
const double test2 = 5;
constexpr double result2 = square_cstxpr((double)test2);
```

`test2` is not a constant expression because it is not of integral or enumeration type. Consequently, `square_cstxpr` cannot be called at compile time with `test2`as an argument.

Comment: Can you comment on why `const double` or `const float` not allowed in constant expression besides last statement of Columbo?