# constexpr variable use const variable at initialization

Tags: c++, gcc, constants, constexpr

Why the following example compile with no problems?

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
  
  const int var1 = 2;
  constexpr int var2 = var1 * 5;

return 0;
}
```

According to theory:
*“Variables” that are not constant expressions (their value is not known at compile time)*

I used gcc compiler, can be the case that each compiler behave different?

Then how **const var1** is known at compile time in this example?

I found [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346879/const-vs-constexpr-on-variables) [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/whats-the-difference-between-constexpr-and-const) about `const` vs `constexpr` but I still don't understand it.

Comment: `var1` is a constant expression because it is initialized by another constant expression.

Comment: `const int var1 = something()` COULD be a constant expression. `constexpr int var2 = something()` MUST be a constant expression. In your case `var1` is a constant expression since it is `const` and initialized with an integer literal. So the compiler doesn't mind.

Comment: Because `constexpr int var2`  use in his initalization `var1` will force `var1` to be initialized at compile time ?!

Comment: This is a special case. Any `const` integral types initialized with constant expressions are usable as constant expressions. It has nothing to do with `var2`.

Comment: @Mihai Whether you defined `var2` or not is irrelevant. The point is that `var1` itself is a constant expression as it is a `cont` int variable whose initializer is a constant expression. This is explained in any beginner [c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: See the explanation and same example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14117121/12002570). In particular because *"This is possible because var1, being constant and initialized at declaration time with a literal, satisfies the criteria for a constant expression, even if it isn't declared constexpr."* An even better dupe: [The value of a const variable is or is not usable in a constant expression, depending on the variable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593044/the-value-of-a-const-variable-is-or-is-not-usable-in-a-constant-expression-depe)

Comment: Thank you for help is great. Also I want to highlight the comment of @Jason Liam because from his link I found "C++ Primer" book where is explained very well this aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the following example compile with no problems?

The full-expression of any `constexpr` variable has to be a constant expression, i.e evaluable at compile-time.

Your initializer `var*5` is a constant expression because `var` is const-qualifed integral type that is itself initialized by integral constant expression; also `5` is also an integral constant expression, hence, the full-expression `var*5` is also a constant expression. So nothing will cause the program to be ill-formed.