# Confusion about template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

Lately I practiced the use of `template` in c++, and I am confused about one of the template parameters during the process.

For instance, in the following code, the input `A` of `template<typename A>` served as a 'type' to construct function and variables.

```
template <typename A>
A add_simple(A a, A b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

However, in the following example, a unit conversion operation, it seems the input `M1` and `M2` serve as objects. In `main()`, I've shown how the struct is expected to be called.

```
// create a template struct Measure with value and unit. e.g. Measure<int, Unit>::value
template<int v, Unit u> struct Measure{
    static const int value=v;
    static const Unit unit=u;
};

// Conversion struct. expected input two 'Measure' objects. 
template <typename M1, typename M2> 
struct Measure_add {
public:
    // other implementation

    static constexpr int value=M1::value+M2::value;
};

int main(int, char**) {

    std::cout << Measure_add< Measure<10,Unit::m>,
        Measure<20,Unit::m> >::value << std::endl;

}
```

So my confusion about template is:

1. Is `<template>` designed to be such flexible that it dynamically distinguish the input so both a 'type' input and 'object' input works. Or the difference met here because the expected inputs are constructed template input `Measure`? As a result, M1 and M2 are still 'type', `Measure`. And in this case, why `M1::value` is available if M1 is a type instead of an object?
2. Why is it available to get access to `M1::value` or `M2::value` in template struct `Measure_add` though the inputs are unknown to such struct. In other words, if I input other parameters which don't contain attribute `value`, would it cause problem?

Comment: If `value` is a __static__ data member, you don't need an object, only a type. That's what `static` is for.

Comment: @Evg Thanks. And why can the struct I showed here accept unkown attribute of M1, M1::value? What if the inputs M1 and M2 are not `Measure` type or they don't have attribute named `value`?

Comment: Any types with `value` static data members will work in your code example. If either doesn't have a `value` static data member, you'll get a compilation error.

Comment: @Chrsi you could just try it, right? Pass int as m1 and see what happens. Also: does the code compile as you posted it? I'm surprised that you initialize a constexpr variable from const variables, I would expect that not to work.

Comment: @Wutz Yes, I've tried and they are good to be compiled and run. I just don't know why it works though :[.

Comment: @Wutz It's possible because `const` variable initialized with a literal value is treated as a constant expression. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593044/the-value-of-a-const-variable-is-or-is-not-usable-in-a-constant-expression-depe

Comment: Unrelated: it should be `static constexpr int` or `inline static const int` (if for some reason it can't be `constexpr`) to avoid [potential linkage problems](https://godbolt.org/z/q9Tzd65je).

Answer (score 1):

In your code both `M1` and `M2` are type template parameters. The reason why you can say `M::value` is that `value` is a static data member in a type that is substituted for `M`. That's the point of a `static` data member: you don't need an object to access its value. This is not related to templates:

```
struct M {
    static constexpr int value = 0;
};

int foo() {
    return M::value;   // OK
}
```

`M1` and `M2` are not constrained to being specializations of `Measure` template: they can be any types that have a static `value` data member. For other types that don't satisfy this condition you'll simply get a compilation error.

```
std::cout <<
    Measure_add<
        std::integral_constant<int, 10>,
        std::integral_constant<int, 20>
    >::value;  // compiles, prints 30
```

and

```
std::cout << 
    Measure_add<
        Measure<10, Unit::m>,
        std::integral_constant<int, 20>
    >::value;  // compiles, prints 30, but makes no sense
```