# how to compare unknown elements of an array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

Sorry for bad English .
I was trying to write a program that gets a number and see if the digits of an entered number are repeated or not . I did try to if(analyse[0]==analyse[1]==analyse[2]==...) but since I don't know exactly how many elements will array have, it didn't work

```
#include<iostream>
int main(){
    int number,number_help;
    const int count{10};
    std::cin>>number;
    number_help = number ;
    int digitcount{0};
    while(number_help>0){
        number_help/=10;
        digitcount+=1;
    }
    int analyse[count]{};
    for(size_t i {0}; i<digitcount ; i++){
        analyse[i] = number%10;
        number/=10;
    }
    //I don't know what to code here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `analyse` always has 10 elements. Anyway, `a == b == c` doesn't do what you think is does. [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should help.

Comment: If `count` is an integral constant initialized with a literal (`10`, here), the code is OK - `count` [can be used as a constant expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593044/the-value-of-a-const-variable-is-or-is-not-usable-in-a-constant-expression-depe).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik What's wrong with `int analyse[count]{};`?  `count` is a constant expression.

Comment: Bit off-topic, but if you would use [std::vector<int>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of "C" style array for analyse you don't have to precalculate its size, you can just push_back more numbers. std::vector is the type to use when you don't know array sizes up front.

Comment: you know how to write a loop, you know how to comapre two elements for equality. Thats basically all you need to compare all elements of the array for equality

Comment: Input the number as a string.  Much easier to compare and count digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your approach: count how many there are of each digit instead of comparing them to each other.
This is much simpler.

Example:

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    int number;
    std::cin >> number;
    const int count{10};
    int frequency[count]{};
    do {
        frequency[number % 10] += 1;
        number /= 10;
    } while (number != 0);
    for (int i{0}; i < count; i++) {
        if (frequency[i] > 1) {
            std::cout << i << " was repeated " << frequency[i] << " times.\n";
        }
    }
}
```