# Initialize class variable float array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I'm trying to initialize a class variable array. As I understand normal class variable initialization works like this:

```
class test
{
public:
    static const float f;
};
```

However, as an array, it suddenly doesnt work:

```
class test
{
public:
    static const float f[2];
};
//const float test::f = { 1 ,2};
```

The whole code should work, but I commented out the line 6. In line 4, it still threw

> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static float const *
>   const test::f"

I tried pointers and dynamic allocation, both of which didn't work either. How can I fix this error, and is there something wrong with line 6?

Comment: Looks like you forgot the size.  Try `const float test::f[2] = {1 , 2};`

Comment: first of all , the variable F is const , it means that you can't do f[0] = value or f[1] = value , it's read only variable , so you must initialize it at the first  , and secondly , you cannot access to a class obj variable like const float test::f = {1,2} , but only test::{1,2};

Comment: check here,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370283/why-cant-i-have-a-non-integral-static-const-member-in-a-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation

[`static`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) `test::f` means that `f` is not bound to `test` class instances. In other words, there is only one, single `f` like if `test` was `namespace`, not `class`. There is only one and exactly one `f`.

#### Note

Also, You've forgot to add size of `f` array which must be given at compile time.
You can also always use [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) specifier that will automagically provide correct type of member for you.

#### Basic example

```
#include <iostream>

class test
{
public:
    static const float f[2];
};

decltype(test::f) test::f = {1, 2};

int main(){
    // Outputs: 1, 2
    std::cout << test::f[0] << ", " << test::f[1];
}
```

#### Modern example

More modern solution would use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), [initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list), [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) placeholder type specifier and [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) specifier. In that case, you don't need to provide array size at all.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

class test
{
public:
    static constexpr auto f = std::array {1.f, 2.f};
};

int main(){
    // Outputs: 1, 2
    std::cout << test::f[0] << ", " << test::f[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @NathanOliver was saying, you can add the size to your initialization outside of the class:

```
class test                                                                   
{                                                                            
public:                                                                      
    static const float f[2];                                                 
};                                                                           
...                                                                          
const float test::f[2] = {1, 2};
```

Alternatively, you can also use `constexpr` and declare the array within the class itself:

```
class test                                                                  
{                                                                           
public:                                                                     
    static constexpr float f[2] = {1, 2};                                   
};
```